# Formula for a paraboloid-like shape

Tags: geometry

I am looking for a formula to describe a "bowl-like" shape ... imagine a function to describe a kitchen/bath sink (with the minimum being only around the drain).
I am certain I am unable to find what I am looking for simply because I have no idea what words to enter in the search box to describe the shape.

I believe the shape is a relative of a paraboloid. The best I can describe the shape's characteristics is:

- The rate of descent from each side may be different, meaning that the location of the minimum is not at the center of the shape
- The x-z rectangle from which the shape starts (assuming y-axis is height) can have a slope.